# Can't edit text view after putting swipe gesture on it

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a textview that when I swipe to the right it paste text into it.  The only problem is I can not edit the text view. After I put the swipe gesture onto the textview it won't allow me to edit the text anymore. Once I take the gesture off it works again.

Does anybody know why this happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I dragged the swipe gesture onto my app, I dragged it onto the text view itself.  By doing this it didn't allow me to edit my textview.   When I drug the swipe gesture onto my view and not the textview it allowed me to swipe to paste in that textview while still being able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke on your text field:

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Tell me if that helped.

Comment: I figured out that I have to put the swipe gesture on the view so it still allows me to click into the text view and edit it. Thanks though.